# CSS selectors DIVS and last-child

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to highlight the divs every child but the last but I'm not sure why my selector is not working in this case. I've tried `.qltest .qltest2:not(:last-child)` . I'm I missing anything else?

```css
.qltest .qltest2:not(:last-child) {
  background:blue;
}

* {
  min-height:5px;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="qltest">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qltest">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected Result:
[image: Expected Result:]

Comment: Could you please show us  your expected result?

Comment: added expected result

Comment: It is not clear, so do you want a last child from all div? or only specific divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each div.qltest2 is the only child of each div.block, that's why your code doesn't work. You just need to use div.block to highlight every child but the last

```css
.block:not(:last-child) .qltest2 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="qltest">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qltest">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="qltest2">3</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one child in each block, i assume you want the qltest2  in the block that's not a last child

So this

```
.qltest .qltest2:not(:last-child) {
  background:blue;
}
```

Should be changed to

```
 .qltest .block:not(:last-child) .qltest2 {
   background:blue;
}
```